# NSI script : calling one macro from another using insertmacro gives error

Tags: macros, nsis

I am trying to call 1 macro from another in NSI script. Both the macros have MB_OKCANCEL . It gives following error when compiled:

**
 [exec] Error: label "abort_inst:" already declared in function
**

```
   !include "MUI2.nsh"
OutFile abc.exe

!macro installA
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "A?" IDOK lblinstall IDCANCEL abort_inst
abort_inst:
          ABORT       
     GoTo lblinstall 
lblinstall:
!macroend

!macro uninstallA
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "?" IDOK install_A IDCANCEL abort_uninstall
abort_uninstall:
          ABORT
install_A:
  !insertmacro installA
!macroend


Function .onInit
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "x" "version"
${If} $0 == ""  
    !insertmacro installA 
${Else}
    !insertmacro uninstallA
${EndIf} 


FunctionEnd
Section "required" main_section
SectionEnd
```

Please help

Comment: There must be some other label already declared as abort_inst in your script.

Comment: No, there is no other label with same name

Comment: your given code compiles fine at my end, error maybe in some other part then. can you share your full script ?

Answer (score 0):

(Next time, please make sure your code doesn't do weird line breaks)

When inserting a macro, all the code between `!macro` and `!macroend` will substitute your `!insertmacro`. Therefor, you should't use static labels in macros–you could only insert the macro once (making a macro pointless!) You can use relative jumps (e.g. `Goto +2`) or make your labels dynamic by adding parameters to your labels, e.g.:

```
!macro myMacro param1
    ${param1}_loop:
    MessageBox MB_YESNO "Loop this message?" IDYES ${param1}_loop

    # some more code
    ${param1}_end:
!macroend
```

However, since you don't pass any parameters to your macros, why don't you simply use functions?

```
Function installA
    # your code here
Function

Function uninstallA
    # your code here
    Call installA
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Function call also gives error:  Error: could not resolve label "_LogicLib_Label_2" in function "uninstallA"

Comment: Posting complete script . I think in the given scenario using relative jumps is the only solution? Please let me know how to implement that?

Comment: `!include "MUI2.nsh"
OutFile abc.exe

!macro installA
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "A?" IDOK lblinstall IDCANCEL abort_inst
abort_inst:
          ABORT    
   GoTo lblinstall 
lblinstall:
!macroend

!macro uninstallA
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "?" IDOK install_A IDCANCEL abort_uninstall
abort_uninstall:
          ABORT
install_A:
  !insertmacro installA
!macroend


Function .onInit
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "x" "version"
${If} $0 == "" 
 !insertmacro installA 
${Else}
 !insertmacro uninstallA
${EndIf} 

  
FunctionEnd
Section "required" main_section
SectionEnd`

Comment: Apologiesfor not posting the code in a correct format. Though preceded with ``, still it is not showing up correctly.

Comment: modified the original question to add the new script. Using relative jumps is the only way out? Why is function giving error "Error: could not resolve label "_LogicLib_Label_2" in function "uninstallA""

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by converting one macro into Function, as suggested by @idelberg

Answer (score 0):

Again, as long as you're working with macros, you cannot use static labels. A static label can only be used once in a function or section. Your use of macros would translate to the following:

```
Function .onInit
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "x" "version"
${If} $0 == ""  
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "A?" IDOK lblinstall IDCANCEL abort_inst
    abort_inst:
    Abort       
    Goto lblinstall 
    lblinstall: # FIRST TIME USE
${Else}
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "?" IDOK install_A IDCANCEL abort_uninstall
    abort_uninstall:
    Abort
    install_A:
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "A?" IDOK lblinstall IDCANCEL abort_inst
    abort_inst:
    Abort       
    Goto lblinstall 
    lblinstall: # SECOND TIME USE
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

So, that won't work because of the `lblinstall` label which is being used twice. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
Function installA
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "A?" IDOK lblinstall 
    Abort

    lblinstall:
FunctionEnd

Function uninstallA
    MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "?" IDOK install_A
    Abort

    install_A:
    Call installA
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
    ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "x" "version"
    ${If} $0 == ""  
        Call installA 
    ${Else}
        Call uninstallA
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

(I also took the freedom to strip some unnecessary labels from your example)